# Specific correlation metric for categorical variables where matched values are of primary interest - does it have a name?

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, similarities

Hello fellow StackExchangers,

Let's say I have an experiment where two people are asked several questions, and for each question, they can independently select one of 5 preformed answers (A to E). So the answers may look something like this as an example:

Q1. D C

Q2. B B

Q3. D D

Q4. A E

......

I am interested not in the actual answers selected per se, but in how often the same answer is being selected (such as with Q2 and Q3 above). So I can obtain a measure of similarity/correlation in the answers in the range 0 to 1 simply by summing the number of times the same answer is given and dividing by the number of questions.

What surprises me is that I cannot find a similar scenario anywhere. I just assumed that someone would have named a measure of correlation after this type of scenario where the matching of values is more important than the actual values themselves. Perhaps am I searching with the wrong terms.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: It sounds like you are just talking about calculating a *frequency*, which is more basic than a correlation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to CV.

First, it's not correlation. I know that people use "correlation" to mean "relation" but we shouldn't do that in statistics.

Second, there are several measures of agreement for situations like you describe. Probably the most famous is Cohen's [$\kappa$.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa) It ranges from -1 to 1 and most (maybe all) statistics packages can calculate it for you.

That Wikipedia page also links to several other measures of agreement.

Do any of those meet your needs?

Comment: Thank you Peter, your answer has helped me enormously. I am rather surprised (and embarrased) i did not find this myself, but I think I was on the wrong path from the start.